# Excel - How to locate and sum adjacent cells and over multiple columns based on criteria of other columns cells

Tags: excel

Formula to add all occurrences where a name pops up in a column (multiple columns) and return the summed value of all adjacent cells. For more clarification see
[Example Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvdjp.jpg)

In this circumstance I want it to find all of Jim's adding to 5, all of George adding to 4, and all of Terry adding to 7. The challenge is each column will have the names randomly assorted and some times the name may not show up for that day.

Is it possible to search all days for the month (for this example) and add the total of the adjacent column for each person if I input their name?

I was looking into SUMIF functions but I can only get that to work if its all in 2 columns, with the way this one is approached I can only work through multiple columns.

Thank you for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUMIF, You will need to provide the list of names:

```
=SUMIF(Y:AC,"Jim",Z:AD)
```

Note the offset but same size ranges.  Also change `"Jim"` to a cell that contains the name you want to sum.

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, the way you offset the calculation is what I previously had not understood. Thank you so much for your time and thorough explanation!

Comment: @EricR please mark as correct by clicking the checkmark by the answer.